# Has GTS been shutdown for 4th and 5th generation?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-fourth-generation

I've been trying to use GTS on my Pokemon Diamond, but it never works anymore. It says that the software isn't compatible or something like that and some of my friends have been telling me that GTS has been removed from 4th and 5th gen.

So is it removed or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Yep, all WiFi things (so inluding GTS) from 4th and 5th gen are removed. Official announcement by [Nintendo](http://www.nintendo.com/whatsnew/detail/vyWpoM6CBIe6FjW8NIY7bvzOrgBURhzw) said:

> As of May 20, 2014, certain online functionality offered through Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection is no longer accessible. The discontinued services include online play, matchmaking and leaderboards for many Wii, Nintendo DS and Nintendo DSi games. For a comprehensive list of games and services that are affected, please check http://support.nintendo.com/servicesupdate. Users can still play the games in offline mode, which continues to offer a rich game-play experience.

In the list below with affected games there are the following Pokemon games:

- Pokémon Black Version
- Pokémon Black Version 2
- Pokémon Diamond Version
- Pokémon HeartGold Version
- Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Explorers of Darkness
- Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Explorers of Sky
- Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Explorers of Time
- Pokémon Pearl Version
- Pokémon Platinum Version
- Pokémon Ranger: Guardian Signs
- Pokémon Ranger: Shadows of Almia
- Pokémon SoulSilver Version
- Pokémon White Version
- Pokémon White Version 2

Answer (score 0):

Actually, following an exciting change (I have no idea how this happened) GTS appears to be back for (all?) previous games. Just posted through SoulSilver a global trade offering a Beedrill (name: HelloThere holding a message for anyone still out there) for any old Rattata just to see if anyone else can see it. Was able to access it using the following video:

Hope to see some more folks soon.