# Is there a method of finding Shiny Pokemon as of Gen. 5?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-black-white

I've been playing several Pokemon games over the past number of years, and I've only encountered two WILD shiny Pokemon. As of the present day, my time is spent playing Pokemon White version. Is there a proficient method(s) of spawning shiny wild Pokemon (unknown to me whether or not any known methods would be generalized or limited to this generation or others) that I should know about?

If there are more than one method, which way is the best concerning numerical shiny spawns?

Comment: The techniques vary greatly from generation to generation, so as you are specifically asking about 5th Gen I've updated the tag to match :).

Comment: The answer differs also between BW and B2W2, so it's probably needed another retag.

Comment: are you one of those purists who are anti cheat device? if you are not compelled to try something like actionreplay or other cheat enableing flash carts I cant say the 1/8000 odds qualify as proficient....you could never expect to see let alone guarantee a catch of every shiny wild possible if you played all day every day of your life....

Answer (score 2):

In *Fifth gen* there's a key item called **[Shiny Charm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Charm)**, that increases the chance of encountering a Shiny Pokémon, both in the wild and through breeding.
You can receive that item from Professor Juniper after obtaining all the Pokémon in the National Pokédex, with the exception of event Pokémon. But it's only present in **Pokémon Black 2 and White 2**.

I don't think there's something similar in *Pokemon White*.

**Note:** As a *key item* it **can't** be traded from B2W2 to any other game.

Comment: If I remember correctly, can't you trade a Shiny Charm from Black 2 or White 2 to a Black or White game?

Comment: @Cyberson Nope, you can't trade a key item because they can't be held by a Pokemon.

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot it was a key item.

Answer (score 1):

In Pokemon Black and White only (not Black/White 2), you won't have access to the Shiny Charm, nor is there a PokeRadar as there is in a few other generations, meaning 'chaining' Pokemon is a lot harder if not near impossible. Thus the most reliable method available to you to increase your chances of a Shiny Pokemon is the [**Masuda Method**](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method):

#### What is it?

Named after Game Freak director *Junichi Masuda* who programmed it into the game, the Masuda method is a fan-made term which describes a breeding technique using Pokemon from different language-regions, that results in higher chances of hatching a shiny Pokemon. While the standard encounter rate for a Shiny Pokémon (either in the wild or by breeding) is 1/8192, the Masuda method multiplies this rate by 6 in Generation V, to 3/4096 or about **1/1365**

#### How does it work?

Say you have a Pokemon from a foreign region that you breed with a Pokemon from a different region (either your own region, or another foreign one). For example, a Butterfree from the French region bred with a Butterfree from the US region. Or a Lapras from Japan bred with a German Feraligatr. So long as the regions differ, the extra chances at a shiny will be applied.

Comment: This method sounds to be an interesting one, but another problem remains : I have no Pokemon from foreign regions.

Comment: @SlenderUchiha - yes and unfortunately the [GTS trading services have been shutdown entirely](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201716/has-gts-been-shutdown-for-4th-and-5th-generation), so you'll be restricted to trading with people locally.

Comment: At the very best, I have a friend who has a Japanese Mawile.

Answer (score 0):

in gen 6 (x and y) you can easily "chain fish" and get a shiny pokemon fairly easily. it is not the same in BW2, unfortunately. you'll need to get the shiny charm by obtaining all the pokemon in the game (excluding the four event pokemon). then go to professor juniper and collect the shiny charm. this increases your odds from 1/8172 to 1/2724 i think. then, go into doubles grass and keep walking around. doubles grass basically has two opportunities to get pokemon in one battle, so the 1/2724 rule applies to both pokemon. that is really the only thing, other than the Masuda Method, that you can do to find wild or bred shinies.

there are a few in game shiny pokemon. beat Benga in the White Treehollow or Black City to obtain the shiny Gible or Dratini. I think if you breed with a shiny pokemon, it increases your odds of getting another one. But I am not sure about that.

also, if you just SEE all the pokemon in the game, you can talk to professor juniper and she'll give you the Permit, allowing access to the Nature Preserve, a special area in the game that can only be reached by plane in Mistralton. There, in the center of the Preserve, you'll find a shiny Level 60 Haxorus.

That is about it in BW2, I think. In other games there are more ways to get shiny pokemon, though. Unfortunately, if you do not have access to both Black and White Version 2, you cannot do this, as there are certain Pokemon like Vullaby and Rufflet that can only be found in their respective games.

I hope this helped!